# Bind an ItemsControl to individual properties on a single model?

Tags: wpf

I have a model with a number of `bool` properties, e.g.:-

```
public BasicPreferences
{
    public bool ShowLegend {get;set;}
    public bool ShowLabels {get;set;}
    public bool ShowTooltips {get;set;}
}
```

(Simplified - the real class implements INotifyPropertyChanged).

I currently present these as a series of checkboxes in a grid, something like:-

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition />
       <ColumnDefinition />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition />
       <RowDefinition />
       <RowDefinition />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>

   <!-- First option -->
   <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="Show legend?" />
   <CheckBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" IsChecked="{Binding Preferences.ShowLegend" />
   <!-- Second option -->
   <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="Show labels?" />
   <CheckBox etc...
</Grid>
```

(Again simplified to remove styling, etc)

I plan to create more model classes that inherit from the above class and add `bool` properties of their own, e.g.

```
public AdvancedPreferences : BasicPreferences
{
    public bool IsFooEnabled {get;set;}
    ..etc..
}
```

Clearly I need to find an alternative to my "hardcoded" XAML grid, so is there any way to utilise data binding to display the options in (say) an ItemsControl, *while keeping the model as it is*? I realise the standard WPF solution would be to expose the options as an observable collection, but I wanted to keep the models as they are, with the options as separate properties (which are referenced elsewhere in the application code).

Comment: You may want to consider using [DataTemplates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.DataTemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) with the [DataType property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

In your view model, create an observable collection of objects:

```
public ObservableCollection<object> Preferences { get; set; }
```

Then, add your preferences to this observable collection.

Create a converter which will test the type of the object in the preferences list, and return a visibility based on which type it is:

```
public class IsAdvancedPreferencesConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Type t = value.GetType();

        if (t == typeof(AdvancedPreferences))
            return Visibility.Visible;
        else return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

On your view, create the converter in the window resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ViewModels:IsAdvancedPreferencesConverter x:Key="IsAdvancedPreferencesConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Now, use the following ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Preferences}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <CheckBox Grid.Row="0" IsChecked="{Binding ShowLegend}" Content="Show Legend?"/>
                    <CheckBox Grid.Row="1" IsChecked="{Binding ShowLabels}" Content="Show Labels?"/>
                    <CheckBox Grid.Row="2" IsChecked="{Binding ShowTooltips}" Content="Show Tooltips?"/>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="3" Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource IsAdvancedPreferencesConverter}}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            ...
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <CheckBox Grid.Row="0" IsChecked="{Binding IsFooEnabled}" Content="Is Foo Enabled?"/>
                        ...
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

In this scenario, if the type of the item in the list is an advanced preference, then the grid containing the advanced preferences checkboxes will be visible.

Answer (score 1):

DataForm control can fulfill your need. It gives a visual representation of your model. You need to bind your model to the control and the control will render corresponding UI Elements based on the property types. Like TextBox for string typed properties, checkbox for boolean typed properties and so on. It is highly customizable.

https://wpfdataform.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

The way it is usually done is through a converter. The converter takes your `BasicPreferences` class, and uses reflection to generate `ObservableCollection<object>` of your properties (anything that's necessary for binding).  Later, if you want to differentiate between various property types, you can use `DataTemplate` in `ItemsControl`.

Here is also an example implementation: https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PropertyGrid